# Compare value is not null or empty of any class java

Tags: java

I want compare values of any class in java no matter the type, for example i have next class:

```
public class Car {

    private int windows;

    private int doors;

    private int drive;

    private String model;

    public int getWindows() {
        return windows;
    }

    public void setWindows(int windows) {
        this.windows = windows;
    }

    public int getDoors() {
        return doors;
    }

    public void setDoors(int doors) {
        this.doors = doors;
    }

    public int getDrive() {
        return drive;
    }

    public void setDrive(int drive) {
        this.drive = drive;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

}
```

And this other:

```
public class Moto {

    private String model;

    private String color;

    private int year;

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

}
```

And i want compare if is not null or empty attributes of this class, for example :

```
if(Validator.myClass(objectValue)){

}
else{

}
```

Class Validador example:

```
    public class Validador {


        public static boolean myClass(Object obj){
            Class myClass = null;
            String cla = obj.toString();
            int a = cla.indexOf("@");
            cla = cla.substring(0, a);
            try {
                myClass = Class.forName(cla);
                Field[] fields = myClass.getDeclaredFields();
                int contador =0;
                for (Field field : fields) {
                    System.out.println("Field type is: " + field.getType());
                    System.out.println("Field name is: " + field.getName());
                    if(!field.getName().equals("") && field.getName() != null){
                        contador++;
                    }
                }
                log.info(contador);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return true;

        }

}
```

This line not compare if value is not null or empity this attribute:

```
if(!field.getName().equals("") && field.getName() != null){
```

How to do that?

I currently do it in the following way:

```
if(Nameclass != null && Nameclass.getNameAttributeA != null && !Nameclass.getNameAttributeA.equals(""){

}else{

}
```

Update

Not compare 2 object, only one, but not matter type Object, for example: i have obejct Car.class i want compare all or any attribute this class or do the same with others Object(class).

Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, the question isn't clear. Do you want to compare the two objects above? Do you want to pass an object to a validator class and check if each property conforms to something? Many options..

Comment: Depends on whether you are allowed to change these classes or not. Ideally the classes would be designed in a way so that it's impossible to create invalid instances. This could be accomplished by e.g. removing the setters and passing all attributes as arguments to a constructor which would validate them and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if invalid. But as soon as ORM or Serialization is involved this could get difficult. Can you tell us more about the context in which the classes are used?

Comment: Not compare 2 object, only one, but not matter type Object, for example: i have obejct Car.class i want compare all or any attribute this class or do the same with others Object(class). @FrederikVH

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help then. My knowledge concerning comparison starts when there's 2 or more objects to compare. Don't know how you compare one object to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own validator you can use Apache Commons Validator https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check if and object is not null with the following code:

```
if(motoObject!=null) {

} else {

}
```

But your question is not so clear. Can you add further details?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Class Types, for example in class Car you can use:

```
private Integer doors;//default is null
```

The method you can use for your validation is:

```
public static boolean validator(Object myObject) {
        Field[] fields = myObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            try {
                Object objectValue = field.get(myObject);
                if (objectValue == null || objectValue.toString().length() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("null or empty field = '" + field.getName() + "' in : " + myObject.getClass().getCanonicalName());
                    return false; //or you can throw a exception with a message, is better that return a boolean
                } 
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Something is wrong", ex);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

pd. Sorry for my english, isn't so good